# how to handle challenge action from AWS WAF in Javascript

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I am using AWS WAF to protect one of my backend API from potential bots. I have used `AWSManagedRulesBotControlRuleSet` with all default settings which means that `TGT_VolumetricIpTokenAbsent` responds with the Challenge action if token is expired.

On client side, I have exactly followed the documentation:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-javascript-api.html, and has the following code:

```
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Web ACL integration URL/challenge.js" defer></script>
</head>
<script>
const login_response = await AwsWafIntegration.fetch(api_url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: request_body
  });
</script>
```

This works for 1 or 2 times but after that, AWS WAF starts to return response status 202 with header `X-Amzn-Waf-Action: challenge`
Now, I am not sure what should be done on client side to handle this challenge action.

Any help will be much appreciated.